# Имя компьютера, localhost или имя чего?

Tags: linux, localhost, fedora

Не знаю, даже, как сформировать вопрос.
Переставил сегодня `Fedora` с нуля и в командной строке увидел "неясное" имя:

```
[ekkl@37L4247F27-25 ~]$
```

Что такое `37L4247F27-25` ?

Раньше, насколько я помню был `localhost`.

```
]$ cat /etc/hostname
localhost
```

Переименование

```
]# hostnamectl set-hostname localhost
```

Помогает до перезагрузки системы. Как это "37L4247F27-25" заменить?

---

Добавлю следующее:

```
[ekkl@37L4247F27-25 ~]$ cat /etc/hostname
localhost
```

Иными словами: манипуляции с "/etc/hostname" типа

```
]# hostname `cat /etc/hostname`
```

ещё раз повторю: имеют место только до перезагрузки компьютера. Более того,

```
]# hostname `cat /etc/hostname`
[root@37L4247F27-25 ~]#
```

не меняют "37L4247F27-25" в текущей консоли, только в новь открытой. Кажется мне, если бы изменения были глобальными, имя поменялось бы уже в следующей командной строке. Ну это предположение.

Comment: Да правьте файл /etc/hostname, это должно вам помочь.

Comment: Попробуйте эти способы http://debian-help.ru/articles/izmenit-hostname-na-servere-s-debian-linux/

Comment: `grep -Ev '^\s*(#.*|$)' /etc/host{s,.conf,name}` и `grep -r 37L4247F27-25 /etc` покажи/посмотри что ли... и есть ли в системе что-то необычное? может она состоит в каких-то доменах? или это какая-то виртуальная система?

Comment: @fat-zer https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/MYXW4jOD70P8BMYAY71Cjg

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor, а на что-то валидное пробовал менять (`yuchimenko-pc` например)? если загрузиться с отключённой сетью `localhost` не останется?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а что именно менять? В каком файле?

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor `hostnamectl set-hostname yuchimenko-pc` или вручную в `/etc/hostname` прописать и в ребут...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, интересно: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28086601/Windows-Event-Viewer.html

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor не та ссылка/не то окно?

Comment: @Fat-Zer: на другое валидное меняется, при замене на локалхост, обратно до бла-бла сбросилось. Дальше: 37L4247F27-25 это имя для компьютера встречается для Виндовса (второй системой стоит) именно 37L4247F27-25, похожего 37L4247F25-25 или 37L4247F29-25 нет. (Если в гугле искать)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как написано в [**man 1 hostnamectl**](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/hostnamectl.html)

> ... and the transient hostname which is a fallback value received from network configuration. If a static hostname is set, and is valid (something other than localhost), then the transient hostname is not used.

Таким образом при установке в `/etc/hostname` значения `localhost` судя по всему при загрузке <s>[hostnamed](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/hostnamed/)</s> кто-то устанавливает имя хоста в некоторое значение полученное от сетевых служб (DHCP, DNS, возможно (хотя и вряд ли) mdns, NIS или wins. Скорей всего это имя осталось закешировано роутером со времени запуска другой ОС на текущей сетевой карте с данным MAC'ом/IP адресом.

Способ заблокировать данное поведения я не знаю, но не вижу особых причин использовать безликое имя вроде localhost на постоянной основе.

Comment: Ну пусть будет и так. Не вижу причин больше тратить на это время.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно помню эта настройка хранится в /etc/hostname. Поправь там имя хоста и выполни

```
hostname `cat /etc/hostname`
```

что бы система скушала новое имя.

Comment: Это не поможет, после рибута проблема не исчезнет. Было у меня такое очень давно на дебиане. Как пофиксил - не помню, но явно не тем способом, какой вы предложили!

Comment: Не помогло. В hostname прописано localhost